# Why do some tags display short information and some not?

Tags: discussion, tags

In Tags -> name, I see this:

[image]

Which made me think that the tags that didn't display a short information text didn't have one!

Of course that's not the case, but what's the difference, that makes some display info and others not?

<sub>I was trying to edit a tag which had no info. That's why I went there, since I don't remember its name.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those tags are synonyms of another tag that has a tag excerpt/wiki:

> [image: ajax==.ajax]

In some strange cases the synonym may have a wiki/excerpt of its own. If it does, it will display instead of the main one.